# How to align border to background color between two div?

Tags: html, css, background-color

Consider the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZB42ak636Tr3tbw7ISoT?p=preview)

Here is the CSS

```
.border {
 display: inline;
 height: 20px; 
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 40px;
 padding-right: 40px;
 border: 3px solid #eee;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}

.background {
  display: inline;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(74, 144, 226, 0.8);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border: 0px solid #eee;
}
```

Here is what the two `divs` looks like

[image]

As you we can see the border does not align the background color.

What is the reason to this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because border is added to outside of the `div`. If you want to align it you can add `box-sizing: border-box;` or use box-shadow inset instead of border.

Comment: Adding `box-sizing` does not work, consider this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XOQY3ISY6GtyPZleOXkf?p=preview)

Comment: You would need to add the vendor prefixes though

Comment: @WimMertens - Note that [`box-sizing` is pretty much universally supported without any prefixes](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)... prefixes are not needed.

Comment: Thanks, yes you're right. Hard to keep track of what to prefix and what not :)

Answer (score 0):

I used `box-shadow` to fix this

```css
.margin_css {
  margin: 50px;
  
}

.border {
  display: inline;
 height: 20px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 40px;
 padding-right: 40px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
     -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #eee;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #eee;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #eee;
}

.background {
  display: inline;
 height: 20px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 40px;
 padding-right: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(74, 144, 226, 0.8);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border: 0px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <div class="margin_css">
    Margin
  </div>

  <div class="border">
    border
  </div>
  <div class="background">
    background
  </div>
  
   <div class="margin_css">
    Margin
  </div>
  

</html>
```

Comment: if i zoom it, not equal to background

Comment: Sorry, It was border causing the problem.updated the snippet

Answer (score 0):

This is from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). It explains how heigh and width are actually calculated.

> The total width of an element should be calculated like this:
>
> Total element width = width + left padding + right padding + left border + right border + left margin + right margin
>
> The total height of an element should be calculated like this:
>
> Total element height = height + top padding + bottom padding + top border + bottom border + top margin + bottom margin

You can use the css `box-sizing` attribute to tell the browser to include more than just element content in the set height and width.  Setting `box-sizing: border-box` means that the browser will include everything from the border in as part of the set width and height.  The default is `box-sizing: content-box`, which excludes the additional width of padding, margin, and borders.

Answer (score 0):

If you want perfectly, border size should remove from padding of background like the following

```css
.border {
 display: inline;
 height: 20px; 
 padding-top: 7px;
 padding-bottom: 7px;
 padding-left: 37px;
 padding-right: 37px;
 border: 3px solid #eee;
 font-size: 1.4em;
}

.background {
  display: inline;
  height: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(74, 144, 226, 0.8);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  border: 0px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
  <br><br>
        <div class="border"></div>
        <div class="background"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using i element with fix height and width. If you are using padding to create height of a element then you have to take care that if you are using an extra property in an element which will increase you height then you have to manage it with padding you have given.

Use this code in you `.border` and it will work fine.

```
.border {
  display: inline;
    height: 20px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
  border: 3px solid #eee;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```